# Javascript: dragging divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know how dragging objects (divs) around on the screen by mouse-click-and-hold implemented using pure JS? I am interested in the native JS functions and the technique which may be used.

Further, how can we do this using jquery?

Comment: Typically when someone says they want pure JS, they mean that they don't want to use a framework (aka "vanilla").  However, you have jquery as a tag here, so which is it?

Comment: I would use Jquery for implementation (saves a truckload of effort) but I am interested in the technique behind such an implementation.

Comment: You can always view the jQuery source code. However, most of the things are implemented more than one time (for different browsers). So it's not very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read [Generic Drag](http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/drag/) article. It works with "pure" JavaScript.

However, I still recommend jQuery UI because it's more feature-rich and probably cross-browser.

In jQuery UI this is [easily](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) done using $('#divId').draggable();

Comment: Great article there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `jquery ui-draggable` for this:

```
<div id="draggableDiv">
content here
</div>
```

`javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#draggableDiv").draggable();
  });
```

Don't forget to include:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

See the working example here >>
http://jsbin.com/ocugo

And for pure JavaScript solution (without any framework), here is a nice tutorial: http://blogs.oracle.com/ahot/entry/javascript_how_to_make_draggable